# Is it impossible to use systemd for services that will not have a PID like docker/docker-compose/podman results?

Tags: systemd, docker, docker-compose

I want to systemd-ize our docker/docker-compose/podman setups, but it seems that systemd is incapable of properly dealing with service units that end without leaving a process behind. That is problematic, because the tools in question work by calling an API, scheduling processes to start but not spawning or forking them themselves, so by the time a call to, say, docker-compose returns, no processes are visible for systemd, so any variation of Type/RemainAfterExit still leads to the service marked as stop/dead/stopping/etc., because no surviving PID is detected.

I am not sure if this is relevant, but I run in userspace with `--user`. Lingering is enabled for the user.

This is one of my many attempts at getting systemd to work, but like any other combination of settings, it gets stopped after 5 seconds:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=%u service with docker compose
BindsTo=podman.service
After=podman.service

[Service]
Environment=DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/%U/podman/podman.sock
Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/%U
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/srv/podman/%u
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose down -v

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I start above file with `systemctl --user start myservice.service`. It produces an output like this:

```
May 04 14:10:27 myhost systemd[841]: Starting myservice service with docker compose...
May 04 14:10:27 myhost docker-compose[106023]:  Container nginx  Creating
May 04 14:10:27 myhost docker-compose[106023]:  Container nginx  Created
May 04 14:10:27 myhost docker-compose[106023]:  Container nginx  Starting
May 04 14:10:27 myhost docker-compose[106023]:  Container nginx  Started
May 04 14:10:27 myhost systemd[841]: Finished myservice service with docker compose.
May 04 14:10:32 myhost systemd[841]: Stopping myservice service with docker compose...
May 04 14:12:03 myhost systemd[841]: myservice.service: Stopping timed out. Terminating.
May 04 14:12:03 myhost systemd[841]: myservice.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
May 04 14:12:03 myhost systemd[841]: myservice.service: Unit process 106072 (docker-compose) remains running after unit stopped.
May 04 14:12:03 myhost systemd[841]: Stopped myservice service with docker compose.
May 04 14:12:03 myhost docker-compose[106072]:  Container nginx  Stopping
May 04 14:12:03 myhost docker-compose[106072]:  Container nginx  Stopped
May 04 14:12:03 myhost docker-compose[106072]:  Container nginx  Removing
May 04 14:12:03 myhost docker-compose[106072]:  Container nginx  Removed
```

Comment: I must admit, I generate my pod startup scripts by creating a pod (which is what your docker-compose probably does when you "up"), and then use `podman generate systemd` to give me a set of service files that depend on each other in the right order.

Comment: Unfortunately, docker-compose doesn't create pods, and we have too many existing compose configurations to just start from scratch and write a gazillion pod definitions :(

Comment: `podman-compose` does @Torque

Answer (score 1):

When executing `docker-compose` from `systemd` you do not want to daemonize (remove the `-d` option from your `ExecStart`) so `systemd` can properly track it.

You probably also do not need to declare the `Type=` or `RemainAfterExit=` options as the defaults should be fine for `docker-compose` services.

If you want to make services for individual containers, I would advise you look at the output of `podman generate systemd` for one of your containers and adjust your Docker service files to be similar.

Another note: the `podman.service` is not supposed to be constantly running as it is invoked from `podman.socket`.  Setting `After=` to reference `podman.socket` may be closer to the behavior you are expecting.  I am not sure the `BindsTo=` option is what you are looking for.  While the `podman.socket` would be required for running `docker-compose` commands, it is not required for running the containers and I am not sure you would want all of your containers to restart when the Podman API is restarted.

With all that, your posted service file would look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=%u service with docker compose
After=podman.socket

[Service]
Environment=DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/%U/podman/podman.sock
Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/%U
WorkingDirectory=/srv/podman/%u
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up --remove-orphans
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose down -v

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

These have been my experiences with running `podman` and `docker-compose` through `systemd`.  Hopefully some of that helps you craft working services for your containers.

Comment: Your point about the correct service name being `podman.socket` instead of `podman.service` was actually the reason for my problem. I would accept your answer, but I have been warned against leaving non-detached docker-compose instances open for weeks at a time like this so I am not sure I should. Are you certain that that is a good idea ?

Comment: If you have documentation about leaving non-detached `docker-compose` containers running, I would to see it.  I cannot think of any problems off the top of my head, and all of my `docker-compose` `systemd` services work this way.  `systemd` wants all services to run in the foreground to track them properly.  If there is an issue with `docker-compose` running that way, it is news to me.